# Windows 8 input[type="range"] bad on touch devices

Tags: css, windows-8

I'm developing this app for win8 platforms and I ran into a problem with the input[type="range"] (sliders) that when you want to move the slider thumb, you often slide the hole background instead of just the slider thumb.

Their is a input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb selector but it seems that it's only working on the x-axis because of the area around it overflow hides the y axis.

Does anybody have a work around to increase the size of the thumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `-ms-touch-action: none;` CSS property to the input element to disable panning when touching that element, and then it should work better.